# Is it possible to grab the current coordinates X, Y, of touchscreen devices remotely on a windows network on Windows 10?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mouse, remoting, touchscreen

multiple computers, looking to grab X, Y, coordinates of 100 touchscreens across a network to search for phantom touches or faulty screens.

these events should be transmitting back to the computer and if I scan each computer it should show me the X, Y, coordinates of each location of the touch, can this be achieved? if so which methods can be implemented as I believe there may be multiple ways of getting this info?

Comment: `there may be multiple ways of getting this info` - what's one way?

Comment: I've been discussing this with a few friends, they are mentioning that .net and python as well as JavaScript can grab X,Y coordinates remotely? I've been searching for some code online that will allow me to do this, I'm not even sure if it's ever been done.